# Interpretation of $dx/dt$ and $u$ in Mass conservation & Euler Equation System

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, computational-physics, differential-equations

I am currently studying CFD and I have a question about how I should interpret the term $u$ and $dx/dt$. I would like to find that out in the textbook, but I could not.

When I solve 1D Euler Equation with Mass conservation

$$
\begin{gathered}
\partial_{t} \rho+\partial_{x}(\rho u)=0 \\
{\partial_{t}(\rho u)+\partial_{x}(\rho u u)+\underbrace{\partial_{x} p}_{=\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_{s} \partial_{x} \rho=c^{2} \partial_{x} \rho} \partial_{x} \rho}=0
\end{gathered}
$$

then I get the result

$$
c \frac{\mathrm{d} \rho}{\mathrm{d} t}+\rho \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} t}=0 \text { if } \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{~d} t}=u+c → 
\frac{c(\rho)}{\rho} \mathrm{d} \rho+\mathrm{d} u=0 \text { along } \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{~d} t}=u+c
$$
or
$$
c \frac{\mathrm{d} \rho}{\mathrm{d} t}-\rho \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} t}=0 \text { if } \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{~d} t}=u-c . →\frac{c(\rho)}{\rho} \mathrm{d} \rho-\mathrm{d} u=0 \text { along } \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{~d} t}=u-c
$$

In the result I have a problem about how to interpret these two terms $u$ and $dx/dt$. As I understand, both terms were the flow velocity like $u=dx/dt$. The fact that the meaning of these terms diverges confuses me.

Comment: Images are not accessible to all users. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/404425) for typing out variables and equations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I modified.